# Add Int to DateTime

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns `RegisterDate` and `ActiveDays` (int)

I want to add ActiveDays to RegisterDate  and compare it to date of now

I usee below query

```
select RegisterDate  + INTERVAL  cast(ActiveDays as text) || ' day' .....
```

but it results in the error:

> syntax error at or near "cast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the error you get, you have this:

```
INTERVAL  cast(ActiveDays as text) || ' day'
```

At first sight, this looks like it should work the same as:

```
INTERVAL '5 day'
```

But here `INTERVAL` isn't actually a cast operator, it is an annotation of the type of the literal string - basically, defining what the quote marks mean.

If you switch it over to a normal `CAST`, it would work:

```
CAST(CAST(ActiveDays as text) || ' day' as INTERVAL)
```

Or you can use Postgres's non-standard `::` cast operator, which makes it a bit more readable:

```
(ActiveDays::text || ' day')::interval
```

Or, as [klin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821981/157957) suggests, you could take a different approach, and multiply a single day by the appropriate integer:

```
ActiveDays * INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Note that here I am using the literal syntax that you tried to use earlier.